# Как удалить словарь из списка словарей

Tags: python, словари, for, dict

Есть список словарей

```
a = [
    {
        'key': 1,
        'value': 10
    },
    {
        'key': 2,
        'value': 5
    },
    {
        'key': 3,
        'value': 7
    },
    {
        'key': 4,
        'value': 27
    },
    {
        'key': 5,
        'value': 96
    },
    {
        'key': 6,
        'value': 3
    }
]
```

Необходимо, чтобы при сравнении двух элементов по определенному условию удалялся словарь, который не подходит под это условие. Например, при сравнении двух элементов удалять тот, где значение ключа 'value' меньше.
Необходимо сравнить каждый элемент с каждым, а не просто соседние элементы. И нужно, чтоб элемент не соответствующий условию, сразу удалялся, и при этом не нарушалась итерация цикла.
Тогда на выходе надо получить:

```
a = [
    {
        'key': 5,
        'value': 96
    },
]
```

Пример решения

```
    delete_chars = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        value1 = a[i].get('value')
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
            value2 = a[j].get('value')       
            if value1 < value2:
                delete_chars.append(a[i])
            else:
                delete_chars.append(a[j])

a = [i for i in a if i not in delete_chars]
```

P.S. решение подходит, но можно ли как то обойтись без создания нового списка, а непосредственно в цикле удалять неподходящие значения

Comment: Чтобы ничего не нарушалось, лучше сразу создавать новый список. Ну, либо, если прям нужно удалять именно из текущего, то итерироваться по копиям списков.

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд, задача выглядит как поиск максимума среди значений словаря. Тогда так:

```
a = [max(a, key=lambda x: x['value'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень сомневаюсь в эффективности и необходимости данного и нужного решений. Я бы использовал простой цикл с поиском максимального значения и запоминанием индекса словаря где оно содержится. И создавал список с этим словарём.

```
max_val = float('-inf') # минус бесконечность(что бы любое значение было больше)
max_index = -1

for ind in range(len(a)):
    val = a[ind]['value']
    if val > max_val:
        max_val = val
        max_index = ind

a = [a[max_index]]
```